# AppleScript in Xcode11 and Catalina

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I am trying to make my ObjC application scriptable. I included .sdef file into my project, created appropriate classes, very simple, just one command. Anyway, Apple Script Editor can't read my dictionary[image]
I checked evrything twice, tested similar srciptable project from Ray Wenderlich tutorial, the result is the same. Are there any changes in Catalina or sandboxing or anything else?
Thank you.

Comment: Check the OSAScriptingDefinition field in Info.plist points to the .sdef file.

Comment: It is there, has the same name.

Comment: Go it: name of .sdf file MUST be all small caps!!! Jeez.... My was like MyApp.sdef, the same was in info.plist. When I changed the name of file to "myapp.sdef" and name of "Scripting definition file name' in info.plist to "myapp.sdef" it woks.